# How did the Tachyon pulses converge when they were emitted at totally different times?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In TNG: "All Good Things":

One tachyon pulse is emitted by the enterprise in the present, one by the enterprise 7 years earlier and one by the Pasteur years into the future. How exactly do they converge together to create the anomaly if they were emitted at different times in history?

Comment: When you screw with time, it gets bendy on you.

Comment: Related; [Were the “All Good Things…” tachyon pulses identical or not?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/125357/were-the-all-good-things-tachyon-pulses-identical-or-not)

Answer (score 3):

Tachyons travel backwards in time.  (That's what defines a tachyon.)  So since they were emitted at different points in space, they could travel different amounts of time backward and all converge at some point in the past.

Answer (score 2):

The pulses were emitted at the same point in space where the anomaly was. Because the pulses were travelling through time, when they were emitted was irrelevant.  All three converge and build up over (under?) time.  Q's smug face on this episode was rightfully deserved.